# How to create a thread using twitter-api-v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I want to create a thread using [`twitter-api-v2`](https://npmjs.com/twitter-api-v2) package. What i'm currently doing is as follows

Create A tweet `==>` Get the tweet id of the newly created tweet `==>` Replay to the tweet `==>` Repeat

But, i feel this is not an efficient way. Any method to create a thread and post it at once ranther than tweeting again and again?

Comment: The [available actions](https://github.com/plhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/HEAD/doc/v2.md) for `twitter-api-v2` include [post a thread of tweets](https://github.com/plhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/HEAD/doc/v2.md#Postathreadoftweets). Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct, Twitter API doesn't provide a way to create threads with a single request.

You can use `tweetThread` [method](https://github.com/plhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/master/doc/v2.md#Postathreadoftweets) as suggested by D M in the comment. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/36821932dbde93129168e8b47af4e1e377552bde/src/v2/client.v2.write.ts#L145), you can see it does exactly what you already implemented.